# Program cannot calculate the root for a quadratic equation

Tags: c

I have to write a simple program that can find the roots for a quadratic equation (ax^2 + bx + c) by inputting the values of a, b and c, and using the if-else statement. The program can compile, but the answers came out totally wrong. my data types for all my inputs and outputs is double

I tried looking at my formulas but it seems like nothing is wrong with them?

```
    printf("input values of a, b, c: ");
    scanf("%lf, %lf, %lf", &a, &b, &c);

    disc = pow(b, 2) - (4 * a*c);

    if (a == 0)
    {
        r = -c / b;
        printf("x = %.2lf\n", r);
    }
    else if (disc >= 1)
    {
        r1 = (-b + sqrt(disc)) / (2 * a);
        r2 = (-b - sqrt(disc)) / (2 * a);
        printf("x1 = %.2lf and x2 = %.2lf", r1, r2);
    }
    else if (disc == 0)
    {
        r1 = (-b + sqrt(disc)) / (2 * a);
        r2 = r1;
        printf("2 of the same root, x = %.2lf", r2);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("no real root");
    }
```

for example, when I input 2, -11, and 12 as a, b and c, the answer that is supposed to be displayed is 'x1 = 4.00 and x2 = 1.50' but instead, the output that I got was 'x1 = .00 and x2 = 0.00'. And even for the first condition, I inputted 0, 3 and 6, expecting for the output to be 'x = -2.00' but I got 'x = -1.00' instead.

Comment: have you included the correct headers?

Comment: This is not a program. This is a few statements picked from the middle of a program. Please post a [mcve].  Though `disc >= 1` looks like a typo to me.

Comment: You need to be careful with double comparison. You can use `|a-b|<=eps` to check if a is equal to b. Also, you should use `b*b` instead of `pow (b, 2)`.

Comment: In which form exactly do you input them? You don’t check the return value of `scanf` so does it really read all three? Did you debug line by line to see how the calculations and logic goes?

Comment: You must provide a [mcve].

Comment: sparrabeth, Please post the _exact_ text entered in response to `printf("input values of a, b, c: ");`

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect code looking of real roots.

```
// else if (disc >= 1)
else if (disc >  0.0)
```

Comment: This does not cause the behavior complained of, as neither of the cases has a `disc` between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%lf, %lf, %lf", &a, &b, &c);` tells `scanf` to expect commas between the numerals. When you input numerals separated only by spaces, without commas, then `b` and `c` are not assigned, and they have unspecified values.

To correct this, change `scanf` to:

```
int n = scanf("%lf%lf%lf", &a, &b, &c);
if (n != 3)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error, scanf failed.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

You will also need to insert `#include <stdlib.h>` to declare `exit`.

Additionally, `else if (disc >= 1)` should be `else if (disc > 0)`.